# How to upload a file to google drive?

Tags: sync, rsync, google-drive, grive

I would like to just upload files to google drive from the command line. I don't care about synchronisation. I just want to upload things to google drive and if they exist they get replaced if not they are created.

I know grive exists but that syncs everything from google drive to the folder you use which isn't what I want.

I was wondering if there is a solution to this, through `scp` or something similar?

thanks

Comment: scp and rsync use ssh. AFAIK Google Drive doesn't offer ssh. rsync can also connect to a rsync daemon, but I doubt Google Drive offers that as well. AFAIK they don't even offer FTP, so probably the only way is creating a script using cURL.

Comment: which kind of "hacks" it's way through the browser interface?

Comment: you can check this out https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive

Comment: I just do **`./gdrive-linux-x64 upload yourfile.rar`**. And Then `yourfile.rar` will be uploaded to your gdrive home folder

Comment: The service [Couchdrop.io](https://couchdrop.io/features) acts as middleman and is free up to 1GB

Answer (score 3):

There is a good tutorial: [Google Drive File Upload Using The Terminal](https://medium.com/@ianhutch90/google-drive-file-upload-using-the-terminal-3652ee90a6f6).

To summarize the link:

- If not already installed, install `curl`
- create Google security certificate
- test from command line
- create Python script to automate

Comment: Unfortunately that tutorial is now behind a paywall and cannot be easily referenced

Comment: @ohshazbot No problem. I changed to a different link.

Answer (score 1):

send the file to your gmail account as attachment and from there you can save it to google drive directly.

> uuencode file.txt  file.txt | mail your_email@gmail.com

I know this is not direct to gdrive, but as there is no other options available I use this easy approach.

Comment: Nice trick, pity that's not exactly what's being asked. I need to send a big file and email attachments are restricted to 25MB

Comment: No way that can be called an "easy" approach.

Answer (score 1):

`rclone` is a good answer to your question. Configuration and usage is detailed in [rclone web site](https://rclone.org/drive/).
By using `rclone` you can easily switch to other supported cloud providers described in [rclone home page](https://rclone.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're logged into `gdrive` in the system (in ubuntu settings) - just enter into the root and paste to the directory: `/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=(first_part_of_your_mail_here)`

If you didn't log in - you need to mess up with networking tools.